# Jenkins groovy classpath issue - unable to resolve class

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have an 'Execute Groovy script' build step in Jenkins.  This step consists of two files - a client file called createWorkspaces.groovy and a bean file called WorkspaceBean.groovy.  Both live in the same location in the job workspace.

Previously running Jenkins 1.554 this ran without issues, but after upgrading to 1.594 I am getting the following error:

```
/jenkins/workspace/testjob/scripts/groovy/createWorkspaces.groovy: 75: unable to resolve class WorkspaceBean 
 @ line 75, column 21.
       def workspace = new WorkspaceBean()
                       ^

1 error
```

I have approved the scripts in the new script approval function and I have also added the location of the files to the class path parameter in the job step as well as the location of the jenkins-core.jar file.

Any ideas why this has stopped working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the groovy plugin.  Adding paths to the Class path field within the plugin configuration does not change the class path.

**This does not work:**

[image: Adding here does not work]

Adding a CLASSPATH variable via the 'Inject environment variables into the build process' plugin does work.

**This works:**

[image]

Comment: Have you reported the bug to the Jenkins team? [Here is how](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Issue+Tracking).

Comment: @JamesE, your solution doesn't help

Comment: how is this accepted answer? paste the actual classpath

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your jars dynamically. This is the final working solution I found. This sample is for copy network folder to local machine.

```
def file = new File("jcifs-1.3.18.jar")
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(file.toURI().toURL())


def auth_server = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication").newInstance("domain", "username", "password")
def auth_local = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication").newInstance(null, "local_user", "password")

def source_url = args[0]
def dest_url = args[1]
def auth = auth_server

//prepare source file
if(!source_url.startsWith("\\\\"))
{
  source_url = "\\\\localhost\\"+ source_url.substring(0, 1) + "\$" + source_url.substring(1, source_url.length());
  auth = auth_local  
}
source_url = "smb:"+source_url.replace("\\","/");
def source = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.SmbFile").newInstance(source_url,auth_server)

//prepare destination file
if(!dest_url.startsWith("\\\\"))
{
  dest_url = "\\\\localhost\\"+ dest_url.substring(0, 1) + "\$" +dest_url.substring(2, dest_url.length());
  auth = auth_local  
}
dest_url = "smb:"+dest_url.replace("\\","/");
def dest = Class.forName("jcifs.smb.SmbFile").newInstance(dest_url,auth_local)
source.copyTo(dest)
```